# How could I set up a Kik bot without access to port forwarding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kik

I thought it would be cool to set up a chat bot for Kik, and from what I can tell so far, it doesn't seem so hard code-wise. I've never really been one for understanding servers and whatnot, however, so this part always confuses me. I am on a college campus so I of course don't have any access to port-forwarding, which seems to be necessary for a website called "ngrok" that a lot of guides seem to be using. I'm sure I have options available, but, like I said, I have little to no knowledge of servers and virtual servers and whatnot.

Are there any easy solutions to this that somebody could walk me through? I should be able to figure it out from there!

Comment: I think NGROK will still work on the campus. Try setting it up. If you are getting an error, post it here

Comment: This was the error that I got: https://i.gyazo.com/ab0493a38259877de6ac8a6a34799828.png

Answer (score 0):

use a VPS that has port forwarding to host your bot :)

I'm sure doing a web search for 'VPS'  will yield plenty of results